# Unable to Install Python Packages on Linux

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu-16.04

I am a new to Linux and have dual booted my system. I specifically want to install numpy, darknet or lightnet python packages. I tried following the instructions given [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/darknetpy/2.0)

When I run the below command:

```
pip install darknetpy
```

I am seeing the following error:

```
Collecting darknetpy
  Using cached darknetpy-2.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-5J0HcA/darknetpy/setup.py", line 6, in <module>
        import urllib.request
    ImportError: No module named request
```

I am unable to understand what this error is about. When I tried installing numpy package, I get the below error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/test/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/test/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/home/test/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/home/test/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/home/test/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/home/test/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/home/test/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/home/test/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy-1.13.3.dist-info'
```

Kindly help in solving this error.

Comment: execute as sudo: `sudo pip install darknetpy`

Comment: Tried and I am seeing the error below:  Downloading darknetpy-2.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-NjWiU7/darknetpy/setup.py", line 6, in <module>
        import urllib.request
    ImportError: No module named request
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-NjWiU7/darknetpy/

Comment: then run before: `sudo pip install requests`

Comment: Did and installed packages. WHen I again try sudo pip install darknetpy,

I see below error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-dwXHbE/darknetpy/setup.py", line 6, in <module>
        import urllib.request
    ImportError: No module named request
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-dwXHbE/darknetpy/

Comment: You're using Python 2.7 but the package you're installing only works with Python 3.

Comment: Yes, how should I upgrade from 2.7 to 3.6?

Comment: It can not be upgrade, you must install python3, python2 and python3 are different versions.

Comment: execute: `sudo pip3 install darknetpy`

Comment: When I run python3 --version, I see Python 3.5.2
However when I run python --version I see Python 2.7.12
How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

`OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied` Typically means you the invoker have insufficient permissions.

It looks like you are trying to pip install it using python2, as eyllanesc pointed out the package you're installing is only supported by python3, so you will have to install it first.

Here are some links to help with that:

- http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/07/install-python-3-6-1-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts/
- http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install3/linux/
- https://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-6-on-centos/
- https://gist.github.com/dschep/24aa61672a2092246eaca2824400d37f (Raspbian)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332641/how-to-install-python-3-6 (debian)

Try running the command again with `sudo` as in `sudo pip install darknetpy`, or as a super user (typically gained with `sudo su`) then run the command normaly.

If you are still getting `ImportError`s when you are trying to pip install something, try pip installing the module that is missing.

Comment: If you review the comments you'll see that that's what I said, plus that library is only supported by python3.